# Can't bind params using [FromQuery] ASP Net Core 2 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I'm new in ASP Net Core 2, I want to bind different parameters that come from URL query string to action parameters in my action:

```
[HttpGet("{page}&{pageSize}&{predicate}", Name = "GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria")]
public IActionResult GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria([FromHeader] string idUser, [FromQuery]int page, [FromQuery]int pageSize, [FromQuery]string predicate)
{
    ....
}
```

When I test my action using postman, I set the `idUser` in header and other parameters in URL, example:

```
http://localhost:51232/api/buildings/page=1&pageSize=10&predicate=fr
```

The result is that I receive the `idUser` that I send from the header but other parameters are empty.

Do I miss something or what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those parameter are meant to be in the **query** then there  is no need for them in the **route** template

In

```
[HttpGet("{page}&{pageSize}&{predicate}", Name = "GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria")]
```

`"{page}&{pageSize}&{predicate}"` are placeholders in the *route* template, which is why the `[FromQuery]` fails to bind the parameters.

> `[FromHeader]`, `[FromQuery]`, `[FromRoute]`, `[FromForm]`: Use these to **specify the exact binding source you want to apply**.

*emphasis mine*

Based on the example URL shown and assuming a root route, then one option is to use

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BuildingsController: Controller {

    //GET api/buildings?page=1&pageSize=10&predicate=fr
    [HttpGet("", Name = "GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria")]
    public IActionResult GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria(
        [FromHeader]string idUser, 
        [FromQuery]int page, 
        [FromQuery]int pageSize, 
        [FromQuery]string predicate) {
        //....
    }
}
```

or alternatively you can use them in the route like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BuildingsController: Controller {

    //GET api/buildings/1/10/fr
    [HttpGet("{page:int}/{pageSize:int}/{predicate}", Name = "GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria")]
    public IActionResult GetBuildingsBySearchCriteria(
        [FromHeader]string idUser, 
        [FromRoute]int page, 
        [FromRoute]int pageSize, 
        [FromRoute]string predicate) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)