# what's wrong with my asp.net core controller method?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

In my asp.net core application, we are using the default MVC routing in App StartUp configuration. 
Then in our controller, we have the following code for one of our api endpoint method:

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("services/task/{taskid?}/{taskmessage?}")]
  [Produces("text/html")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> TaskMessage(string taskId = null, string queue = null, string taskmessage = null)
```

Then we are trying to call the endpoint by passing taskmessage only as the following URL:
http://localhost:12345/api/services/task?taskmessage=hello 
However, it's not working here. Can anyone please let me know where did I got wrong? It was working in our ASP.Net project, but once we migrated to the ASP.NET core, it's not working. 
BTW, the version of ASP.NET core F/W we are currently using is ASP.NET Core 2.1, if it matters.

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi @MattU, sorry I didn't make it clear. Not working here means in the URL I passed a value "hello" to the parameter "taskmessage", but in the method parameter, the "taskmessage" is still null. This is our issue.

Comment: I've not tried this in .Net Core. Instead, I use `[FromQuery]` for query string parameters. Like this: `([FromQuery] string taskMessage)`. You can use it for multiple parameters. And the template in the `Route` attribute is simpler.

Comment: Thanks @MattU I know we can use [FromQuery] for the query string parameters. But, from design perspective, I would like to know why is not bind in .Net Core. Why it's different with .Net... But, thank you anyway, I just tried with [FromQuery] and it's working for me

Comment: Also, it's probably better to use the `HttpGet` attribute and supply the route template there. `[HttpGet("route/template")]`. The `[Route]` attribute means the action will accept **all** HTTP verbs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes ... See the green tip in that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this answer to a similar (but different) question states: [Can't bind params using [FromQuery] ASP Net Core 2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485052/cant-bind-params-using-fromquery-asp-net-core-2-api)

> [FromHeader], [FromQuery], [FromRoute], [FromForm]: Use these to specify the exact binding source you want to apply.

They referenced this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1 which talks about the various model binding methods.